# Writing a \sim with the letter a centered above

Tags: tilde

I want something like \sim^a but with the 'a' in the top center not like a power.

Comment: `\overset{a}{\sim}`

Comment: $\stackrel{a}{\sim}$ works also but it is less semantic than $\overset{a}{\sim}$.

Answer (score 5):

See a comparison. Naturally, you might want to define the operator of your choice as a separate macro.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    1&\sim^a x\\
    2&\stackrel a\sim x\\%obsolete
    3&\mathop\sim^a x\\
    4&\overset a\sim x\\
    5&\substack{a\\\sim} x\\
    6&\begin{subarray}{c}a\\\sim\end{subarray} x\\
    7&\buildrel a\over\sim x\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Related.**

- Please read @egreg's valuable comment.
- https://ctan.org/pkg/stackrel
- https://youtu.be/LFrdqQZ8FFc

Comment: Note that `\stackrel{a}{\sim}` is essentially equivalent to `\overset{a}{\sim}`, because `\sim` is a relation symbol. Both end up in doing `\mathop{\sim}\limits^a`, with the big difference that the latter is generally unwanted if not wrapped in `\mathrel` (and you get `a` above `\sim` just by chance, because `align` uses display math mode). Number 7 is the same as number 2, only using a foreign syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Very thoughtful.

Answer (score 2):

Just I'm adding the use of another package called `accents`. Here there are others output but with a lot of sincerity the correct solutions are those referred to the comments and response of the good user @CampanIgnis.

**Edit after the comment of the very nice user** @egreg using `\mathrel`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}


\begin{document}
\textit{one option}, \, $\square\mathrel{\accentset{a}{\sim}}\blacksquare$

\texttt{another options}
\[\triangle\mathrel{\accentset{\displaystyle a}{\sim}}\square\]
\[\diamond\mathrel{\accentset{\scriptstyle a}{\sim}}\square\]
\[\blacksquare\mathrel{\accentset{\scriptscriptstyle a}{\sim}}\triangle\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\accentset{a}{\sim}` does not make the symbol into a relation symbol and `\mathrel{\accentset{a}{\sim}}` should probably be used.

Comment: @egreg A very correct observation, which I have immediately accepted.

Comment: @Sebastiano Imho, this is a valuable complementary answer.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Thank you very very....much for your comment.